# How to use stoppropagation() with input field in angular/ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, input, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I have ionic list. On click of list items pictures are opened. I have input fields inside list items. Need to stop propagation and don't open picture when I click the input field.

`(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` completely works for buttons but doesn't for input field.

Comment: Could you please create a **[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic)** with your code?

Answer (score 0):

For input field you have to use input field events like kryup , key down vice versa