# Trigger change event on ion-select component in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, ion-select

I am trying to trigger a change event everytime I change my option in an ion-select component. The problem is that the change event is triggered when I press the OK button in the popover of the ion-select button. I want to trigger the change event EVERYTIME I select an option.

My initial goal is to select an option and close immediately the popover.

P.S. Please do not propose interface property because I want to keep the design of ion-alert.

Any ideas?

My code:

In my html file:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-select value="-1" (ionChange)="triggerEvent()">
    <ion-select-option value="-1">All</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="a">A</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="b">B</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="c">C</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

In my ts file:

```js
triggerEvent() {
    console.log('event trigger');
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144279/how-to-use-stoppropagation-with-input-field-in-angular-ionic Also why not use (ionBlur) ?

Comment: @mahen23 hi, (ionBlur) is not working, I do not understand how this question will help me since it refers to input. could you please give more details?

Comment: Your question states: "I am trying to trigger a change event everytime I change my option" Which is exactly what your code is doing, as per the tests i've done. 

This is how (ionChange) is supposed to work, user makes a change, the default value: -1 is changed, thus (ionChange) is triggered.

Comment: @mahen23 how were u able to trigger the change event? I am only getting the change event when I press the OK button. are u using ionic 5 right?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve that:

### Solution 1

The one way that I would suggest to do that so easily is to use an `interface="popover"` like this and the output like this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select value="-1" interface="popover" (ionChange)="triggerEvent()">
   <ion-select-option value="nes">NES</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="snes">SNES</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

and the result will look like this:

[image]

### Soultion 2

If you want to stick with the same design you can try to add an event listener when user click on the `ion-select-option` and close the `ion-select` manually it will take some time to implement correctly but it's possible to do that also.